# how to get field1 value of thingspeak channel using python

Tags: python

I want to get the `field1` value of thingspeak channel.

I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'field1'.
```

This is the API response:

```
{"channel":{"id":556464,"name":"pir","description":"pir","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0","field1":"intrusuion","created_at":"2018-08-08T19:04:03Z","updated_at":"2018-08-08T19:41:06Z","last_entry_id":49},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2018-08-08T19:41:06Z","entry_id":49,"field1":"1\r\n\r\n"}]}
```

code

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time

while True:
    TS = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/556464/feeds.json?results=1")

    response = TS.read()
    data=json.loads(response)
    b = data['field1']
    print (b)
    time.sleep(5)   
    TS.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different properties with the name `field1`

The first one you can access via:

```
data['channel']['field1'] # contains "intrusuion"
```

The second one you can get via:

```
data['feeds'][0]['field1'] # contains "1\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint

while True:
  TS = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/556464/feeds.json?results=1")

  response = TS.read()
  data=json.loads(response)
  pprint(data)
  b = data['channel']['field1']
  print (b)
  time.sleep(5)
  TS.close()
```

use the pprint to check how response is having the *feild1* and then you can print it as per your requirement

Comment: its  giving complete response.{'channel': {'created_at': '2018-08-08T19:04:03Z',
             'description': 'pir',
             'field1': 'intrusuion',
             'id': 556464,
             'last_entry_id': 49,
             'latitude': '0.0',
             'longitude': '0.0',
             'name': 'pir',
             'updated_at': '2018-08-08T19:41:06Z'},
 'feeds': [{'created_at': '2018-08-08T19:41:06Z',
            'entry_id': 49,
            'field1': '1\r\n\r\n'}]}
intrusuion

Comment: b = data['channel']['field1']

print (b)

b = data['feeds'][0]['field1']

print (b)

Answer (score 0):

field1 located inside the keys 'channel' and 'feeds'.
You can access them by

```
data[the key]['field1']
```

Comment: getting error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: the field 1 coming like this in the api response. 'field1': '1\r\n\r\n'}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint

while True:
  TS = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/556464/feeds.json?results=1")

  response = TS.read()
  data=json.loads(response)
  b= data['feeds'][0]['field1']
  print (b)
  time.sleep(5)
  TS.close()
```